# Filtering array by input value react

Tags: reactjs, arrays, object, filter

I have a little problem with filtering my array.

I want display a product filtered by input value with a name or platform or something other value. With name is no problem, but i don't know how to do it with platforms.

Bottom is my logic and file with products, txh very much for help

live:  [live](https://gacmen45.github.io/game-shop/)

repo: [repo](https://github.com/gacmen45/game-shop)

```
const [inputText, setInputText] = useState('')

const inputHandler = e => {
        const text = e.target.value.toLowerCase()
        setInputText(text)
}

const filteredData = PRODUCT_LIST.filter(el => {
        if (inputText === '') {
            return
        } else {
            return el.name.toLowerCase().includes(inputText)
        }
})
```

```
const PRODUCT_LIST = [
    {
        id: 'gow',
        name: 'God of War',
        developer: 'Santa Monica Studio',
        category: 'games',
        platform: 'PlayStation 4',
        version: 'PL',
        price: 39,
    },]
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, `inputText` can search either `name` or `platform`. If so, replacing `return el.name.toLowerCase().includes(inputText)` with `return el.name.toLowerCase().includes(inputText) || el.platform.toLowerCase().includes(inputText)` should do

Comment: I would also advise to put the filtering function inside a `useEffect` so it isn't computed at each render of your component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a conditional check.

First, check whether the search text matches the name; if it fits, return the list. If not, then check whether it matches the platform.

```
const filteredData = PRODUCT_LIST.filter(el => {

      const findByName = el?.name?.toLowerCase().includes(inputText);
      const findByPlatform = el?.platform?.toLowerCase().includes(inputText);

        if (inputText === '') {
            return
        } else {
            return findByName || findByPlatform
        }
})
```

Comment: both solutions ending with error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')"

Comment: @Marek It's because some of the elements in `PRODUCT_LIST` don't have a platform. I've updated the code. Please update it.

Comment: @Marek used optional operator to explicitly check the `platform` key.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this just return true when you are getting empty string. Let me know if it works.

```
const filteredData = PRODUCT_LIST.filter(el => {
    if (inputText === '') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return (el.name.toLowerCase().includes(inputText.toLowerCase()) || el.platform.toLowerCase().includes(inputText.toLowerCase()))
    }
})
```

Comment: `inputText` is already in lowercase. No need to do it again.

Comment: ohh I don't see that my fault

Comment: when i addd true, all product are display